# Java returning Generic Type problem: unchecked overriding return type requires unchecked conversion

Tags: java, generics

Hi I am having problems with Generic Types and warning that I get from IDE.
I have class that holds generic type value:

```
public class Result <OUT>{
    private final OUT outputValue;
    
    public OUT getOutputValue() {
        return outputValue;
    }
}
```

I have abstract class:

```
public abstract class CustomSource {

      public abstract <T> SourceFunction<T> getSource();
}
```

and class that extends it:

```
public class OtherCustomSource extends CustomSource {

      @Override
      public SourceFunction<Result<MyEvent>> getSource() {
          ...some code...
      }
    }
```

IDE is giving me warning: unchecked overriding return type requires unchecked conversion.
What I am missing?

Comment: This is due to the fact that `T` is defined as local generic type for `getSource` rather than `CustomSource` class. Define `CustomSource<T>` and revome `T` definition from the abstract method signature. Then redefine `OtherCustomSource extends CustomSource<Result<MyEvent>>` and all should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract <T> SourceFunction<T> getSource();
```

This is not the promise you intended to make. This says "for *every* `T`, I promise I can get a source of type `SourceFunction<T>`." Then you came along and subclassed it with

```
public SourceFunction<Result<MyEvent>> getSource();
```

Which says "specifically, I can get you a source of type `Result<MyEvent>`", a much weaker promise.

If you intend that `getSource` only return one specific type, your generic should be on the `CustomSource` class, not the `getSource` function.

```
public abstract class CustomSource<T> {
  public abstract SourceFunction<T> getSource();
}

public class OtherCustomSource extends CustomSource<Result<MyEvent>> {

  @Override
  public SourceFunction<Result<MyEvent>> getSource() {
      ...some code...
  }
}
```

Then it makes sense to use `OtherCustomSource` as a `CustomSource<Result<MyEvent>>` (since it can get a source of type `Result<MyEvent>`), but it makes no sense to treat a `OtherCustomSource` as a `CustomSource<Integer>`, for example.

Comment: Thx for clarification.