# Change return type of enclosing function to ArrayList<MySpecificObject> from ArrayList<T>

Tags: java, kotlin

I wrote a factory method which takes a class type as an argument and then returns its arraylist from a specific object. Below is my code:

```kotlin
// Factory interface
interface IFactory {
    fun <T: Contentable> create(modelClass: Class<T>): ArrayList<T>
}

// Factory class
class InstructFactory(private val details: Details)
    : IFactory{
    override fun <T: Contentable> create(modelClass: Class<T>): ArrayList<T> {
        return when(modelClass) {
            FirstClass::class.java  -> details.firstList
            SecondClass::class.java  -> details.secondList
            else  -> details.thirdList
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me a compile time error that Change return type of enclosing function to `ArrayList<MySpecificObject>` from `ArrayList<T>`, where my specific object is one of first, second or third class implementing interface Contentable

Comment: Similar to this: [Java:How to override this generic method?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13049420) ... you need a generic interface. Generic methods won't help there.

Comment: You need to cast the list to `ArrayList<T>` to basically overwrite the compiler. The compiler cannot infer that `details....List` matches `ArrayList<T>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java returning Generic Type problem: unchecked overriding return type requires unchecked conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67741623/java-returning-generic-type-problem-unchecked-overriding-return-type-requires-u)